# Graphing library for functions on android

Tags: android, math, graphing

Does anyone know any good libraries that are capable of graphing mathematical functions (eg. x^2/(x-1)) that will show traits such as holes and asymptotes that I would be able to use for an Android app I'm currently developing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that there's a library that can plot a mathematical function like x^2/(x-1). But there are enough libraries for linecharts:

- aChartEngine (I use aChartEngine and it works perfect)
- ChartView
- HoloGraphLibrary
- GraphView

You could always insert into your mathematical funktion a "x" value (eg. 1,2,3) to get the "y" value to plot your mathematical funktion.

```
double x1, x2, x3;
double y1, y2, y3;

x1 = 1.0;
x2 = 2.0;
x3 = 3.0;

public double getYValue(double x){
      double y;
      y = (x * x) / (x - 1);
      return y;
}

y1 = getYValue(x1);
y2 = getYValue(x2);
y3 = getYValue(x3);
```

Do this with 50 or 100 points, add them to the graph and then you get a perfect looking mathematical function.